# How to resize animated GIF with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gif

I am working on an exam project.

I have only just now noticed that my animated GIF that the webpage relies heavily upon does not resize in accordance with neither container or window width. I am using Bootstrap 3 framework.

How is it possible to resize an animated GIF with CSS/HTML? And if that's not possible, what can I use to achieve this as easily as possible?

Comment: Have you tried `width: 1500px; height: 1500px;`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
img.animated-gif{
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="animated-gif" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/Wq6DnHvHchrTG/giphy.gif">
```

Note: Adjust the width size as you want.
Beware never resize more than the actual size, it will be pixelated.

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/95/)**

Comment: Notice that you should set only the `width` - and set `height` to `auto`. Setting both can cause the GIF to resize and lose ratio.

Answer (score 0):

When i've used auto height it didn't fix the issue completly.

I've fixed it for both gif's when i've set the height in pixcels.

example:

```
.gify-img1{
    width: 35%;
    height: 250px;
}
.gify-img2{
    width: 35%;
    height: 250px;
}
```